# Excel 2016 sharepoint file still opens as readonly

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

Since updating to Office 2016 I can't get excel to open a sharepoint file as editable, despite declaring it to do so.

```
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 2), _
    UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False, Local:=True, Editable:=True
```

The file opens without issues, but I have to run a break on the next line to stop the macro and manually select `EDIT`, before allowing the code to proceed.

[image]

Whilst this is an obvious work around, I am looping through about 40 files, and have to do this manually in each open instance.

Comment: I'm hoping someone can find a solution to this; I have a similar issue (files on SharePoint), and this is just a nuisance when you're 30+ files in.  The only work-around suggested to me is a VBA script to make all open files editable, but not upon open.  I haven't tried to build that, yet...

Comment: @Cyril I have found a VBA approach, check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution to this `LockServerFile` is the equivalent of hitting the `Edit Workbook` button.

When opening with VBA you can follow the open command with:

```
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 2)
ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile
```

Solved my problem for now if anyone comes across a similar issue.

Comment: i found that this helps a lot when opening sharepoint files for editing,

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile`

The above code will lock that workbook for editing.
You can edit the workbook and you can save it.
But when you try to open the workbook again by manually, the changes you had done will not reflect in that sheet.

Comment: Maybe, but isn't this just what [Tim Wilkinson's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45171431) states?